# Python: Assistance with json and reading from a file

Tags: python, json

Say i have a notepad file (.txt) with the following content:

```
"Hello I am really bad at programming"
```

Using json, how would I get the sentence from the file to the python program which I can then use as a variable?

So far I have this code:

```
newfile = open((compfilename)+'.txt', 'r')

saveddata = json.load(newfile)

orgsentence = saveddata[0]
```

I always get this error:

```
   return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0:           ordinal not in range(128)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: newfile = open((compfilename)+'.txt', 'r')
   saveddata = json.load(newfile)
   orgsentence = saveddata[0]

Comment: @Kronixion Make that comment as an answer!

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting the code in your comments!

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-using-python. If you got any error, edit your question and write it as well.

Comment: didn't really help

Comment: i have added the code I am using as well as the error message i am getting @manvi77

Comment: It sounds like your file doesn't have plain ASCII quotes (`"`) but rather fancy opening quotes. Try replacing them.

Comment: Did Alex Hall's suggestion fix your problem? If not, please run `print(repr(open(compfilename+'.txt', 'rb').read()))` and paste the output into your question. BTW, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: @AlexHall Thanks it works now! Is there any way of having plain ASCII quotes on Mac because the only ones I am getting are the fancy quotes.

Comment: TextEdit > Preferences > Options > Smart quotes

Comment: @AlexHall didn't change anything

Comment: Quit TextEdit and reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Though you are using `txt` file. You could read this file without `json`. But as you mentioned in the question, you can try like this

hello.txt

```
"Hello I am really bad at programming"
```

To read this `txt` file,

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('hello.txt') as myfile:
    mydata = json.load(myfile) #to load json
    print myfile.read() #to print contents on stdout, not using json load

pprint(mydata)
```

Output:

```
u'Hello I am really bad at programming'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```